# Display an error for that row if a mysql update is not made

Tags: php, csv, mysqli

So the user uploads a stock file csv with all of the products in. The file is formatted are follows :

```
productcode,size1,size2,size3,size4,size5
```

and has that info for each product line.

I have the following code which deals with the uploaded file and pulls that info from the file.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['uploadfile'])) {
    $file = fopen($_FILES['csvfile']['tmp_name'], 'r+');
    while(!feof($file)) {
        $line = fgetcsv($file, 0, ',');

        list($productcode, $v9cm, $v1litre, $v2litre, $v3litre, $v5litre, $v7litre) = $line;

        $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE stock SET 9cm = '$v9cm', 1litre = '$v1litre', 2litre = '$v2litre', 3litre = '$v3litre', 5litre = '$v5litre', 7litre = '$v7litre' WHERE productcode = '$productcode'");
        if ($stmt === FALSE) {
            echo "an error has occured";
        }

        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->close(); 
    }
    fclose($file);
}
?>
```

It seems to work fine and is updating each record in the database as expected, the problem I am having is if I insert a new product code.....lets say bob, so

```
bob,11,44,54,23,12
```

This code 'bob' isn't in the database, so cannot be updated, so there should in theory be an error, but no error is being shown ?.

Comment: You only check for errors on `prepare()`. If I understand your issue, you need to check if anything was actually updated, which is _not_ an error state. It's just that nothing was modified.  Check `$db->affected_rows` after `$stmt->execute()` to determine if anything was modified. It's value will be 0 if no row was matched for `UPDATE`. - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: If you're going to use prepared statements, you really should be using parameter binding as well, to protect yourself against SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

How would your database-server know that you expect exactly 1 row to be updated? Either [check that explicitly](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.rowcount.php) or verify the productcode using a `SELECT` before updating it

Answer (score 0):

Generally before going for update we should always want to check weather that data is available in DB to update, so here in your code before updating the product check weather the productcode is available in db

For eg your code should look like this:

```
while(!feof($file)) {
    $line = fgetcsv($file, 0, ',');

    list($productcode, $v9cm, $v1litre, $v2litre, $v3litre, $v5litre, $v7litre) = $line;

    // check productcode available in db
    $product_stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM stock WHERE productcode= '$productcode'");
    $product_stmt->execute();
    $product_details = $product_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($product_details) {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE stock SET 9cm = '$v9cm', 1litre = '$v1litre', 2litre = '$v2litre', 3litre = '$v3litre', 5litre = '$v5litre', 7litre = '$v7litre' WHERE productcode = '$productcode'");
        if ($stmt === FALSE) {
            echo "an error has occured";
        }
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->close(); 
    } else {
        // your insert query 
            // or
         echo "Product code ".$productcode." not available in DB";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP provides [affected_rows API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) for MySQL exactly for this purpose.